# jquery anchor hover visited tabs of images

Tags: jquery, html, hover, image, visited

I am creating a Images tabs with jquery and i am not using any css here..
I am using anchors `<a>`

When a user hovers on anchor ie focus on `<a>`, it should fire something but its not working

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="TabMenu">
        <span><a href="#"><img src="images/A.png"></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><img src="images/B.png"></a></span>
        <span><a href="#"><img src="images/C.png"></a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to work out with jquery but it not working out, here is code for jquery

```
$(".container .TabMenu span a").click(function(){
 alert("Click working");
});
```

Is there any code where anchors get hover, visited, active

```
$(".container .TabMenu span a:visited").(function(){
 alert("You have visited");
});

$(".container .TabMenu span a:hover").(function(){
 alert("Hover working");
});

$(".container .TabMenu span a:active").(function(){
 alert("Hover working");
});
```

Is there any special functional code for anchor..

and **do not use hover function of jquery** and I know that above 3 anchor code are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To execute code on hover you can use either mouseenter() and mouseleave() methods or the hover () method:

```
$(".container .TabMenu span a").mouseenter(function() {
    alert("hover start")
});

$(".container .TabMenu span a").mouseleave(function() {
    alert("hover end")
});

$(".container .TabMenu span a").hover(function() {
    alert("hover start")
}, function() {
    alert("hover end")
});
```

Comment: there a problem with hover, its diplaying twice hover start and hover end after removing mouseenter and mousleave, can you let me know directly working out with Anchor only, like a:hover, a:visited would be the best

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to do? There are no :visited or :active jQuery filters, but even if there were (or if you wrote custom ones) it would not trigger any callbacks on hover, it would only select visited links from the document...